# Searching a list based on values in another list

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list of names which I'm trying to pull out of a list of strings. I keep getting false positives such as partial matches. The other caveat is that I'd like it to also grab a last name where applicable.

```
names = ['Chris', 'Jack', 'Kim']
target = ['Chris Smith', 'I hijacked this thread', 'Kimberly','Christmas is here', 'CHRIS']

desired_output = ['Chris Smith', 'Kimberly', 'CHRIS']
```

I've tried this code:

```
[i for e in names for i in target if i.startswith(e)]
```

This predictably returns Chris Smith, Christmas is here, and Kimberly.

How would I best approach this? Using regex or can it be done with list comprehensions? Performance may be an issue as the real names list is ~880,000 names long.

(python 2.7)

**EDIT**: I've realized that my criteria in this example are unrealistic given that the impossible request of wanting to include Kimberly while excluding Christmas is here. To mitigate this issue, I've found a more complete names list which would include variations (both Kim and Kimberly are included).

Comment: Why is `CHRIS` there in the output, and not `I hijacked this thread`?

Comment: What approach have you tried so far?

Comment: If `'Kimberly'` is in the output then why `'Christmas is here'` is missing?

Comment: @Ashwini Actually, I think the whole target is viable from what we can tell

Comment: sorry, expanded the description

Comment: Remove strings in `target` composed of more than 2 words. From the remaining check for strings that start with one of the items in `names`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete guess (again) since I can't see how you can not have `Christmas is here` given any reasonable criteria:

This'll match any targets that have any word that starts with a word from names...

```
names = ['Chris', 'Jack', 'Kim']
target = ['Chris Smith', 'I hijacked this thread', 'Kimberly','Christmas is here', 'CHRIS']

import re
matches = [targ for targ in target if any(re.search(r'\b{}'.format(name), targ, re.I) for name in names)]
print matches
# ['Chris Smith', 'Kimberly', 'Christmas is here', 'CHRIS']
```

If you change it to `\b{}\b' - then you'll get ['Chris Smith', 'CHRIS']` so you lose `Kim`...

Comment: This seems to be the most compact and elegant solution. I just added another \b to the end of the search pattern in accordance to my changed criteria based on the edit in my OP

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
names = ['Chris', 'Jack', 'Kim']
target = ['Chris Smith', 'I hijacked this thread', 'Kimberly','Christmas is here', 'CHRIS']

res = []
for tof in target:
    for name in names:
        if tof.lower().startswith(name.lower()):
            res.append(tof)
            break
print res
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no deterministic way to drop the match 'Christmas is here', as it may not be possible for the system to determine if Christmas is a name or something else. 
Instead if you want to speed up the process, you can try this O(n) approach. 
I have not timed it, but definitely faster than your or the proposed solutions.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
names = ['Chris', 'Jack', 'Kim']
target = ['Chris Smith', 'I hijacked this thread', 'Kimberly','Christmas is here', 'CHRIS']
def foo(names, target):
    #Create a generator to search the names
    def bar(names, target):
            #which for each target
        for t in target:
                    #finds the matching blocks, a triplet, (i, j, n), and means that a[i:i+n] == b[j:j+n]
            match = SequenceMatcher(None,names, t).get_matching_blocks()[0]
                    #match.size == 0 means no match
                    #and match.b > 0 means match does not happens at the start
            if match.size > 0 and match.b == 0:
                            #and generate the matching target
                yield t
    #Join the names to create a single string
    names = ','.join(names)
    #and call the generator and return a list of the resultant generator
    return list(bar(names, target))

>>> foo(names, target)
['Chris Smith', 'Kimberly', 'Christmas is here', 'CHRIS']
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I got the rule is that:

1. ignore the case;
2. the target word must be initial with the key word.
3. if the the target word is not exactly the key word, then the target word must be the only word in the sentence.

Try this:

```
names = ['Chris', 'Jack', 'Kim']
target = ['Chris Smith', 'I hijacked this thread', 'Kimberly','Christmas is here', 'CHRIS']
desired_output = ['Chris Smith', 'Kimberly', 'CHRIS']

actual_output = []
for key in names:
    for words in target:
        for word in words.split():
            if key.lower() == word.lower():
                actual_output.append(words)
            elif key.lower() == word.lower()[:len(key)] and len(words.split()) == 1:
                actual_output.append(words)
print(actual_output)
```

It will output **EXACTLY** as your desired output (btw, are you sure you really want this?). Don't be frustrated by the 3-layer loop. If you have N names and M sentences, and the number of words in each sentence is limited, then the complexity of this code is `O(mn)` which can't be better.