# What's a more efficient way of looping with regex?

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list of names which I'm using to pull out of a target list of strings. For example:

```
names = ['Chris', 'Jack', 'Kim']
target = ['Chris Smith', 'I hijacked this thread', 'Kim','Christmas is here', 'CHRIS']

output = ['Chris Smith', 'Kim', 'CHRIS']
```

So the rules so far are:

- Case insensitive
- Cannot match partial word ('ie Christmas/hijacked shouldn't match Chris/Jack)
- Other words in string are okay as long as name is found in the string per the above criteria.

To accomplish this, another SO user suggested this code in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904294/searching-a-list-based-on-values-in-another-list#comment19161454_13904294):

```
[targ for targ in target_list if any(re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(name), targ, re.I) for name in first_names)]
```

This works very accurately so far, but very slowly given the names list is ~5,000 long and the target list ranges from 20-100 lines long with some strings up to 30 characters long.

Any suggestions on how to improve performance here?

**SOLUTION**: Both of the regex based solutions suffered from OverflowErrors so unfortunately I could not test them. The solution that worked (from @mglison's answer) was:

```
new_names = set(name.lower() for name in names)
[ t for t in target if any(map(new_names.__contains__,t.lower().split())) ]
```

This provided a **tremendous** increase in performance from 15 seconds to under 1 second.

Comment: Are all of your names single-word?

Comment: Uh-oh.  @DSM is about to pull out a `str.split` + `set` solution or something similar.  (probably with `timeit` showing how much faster it can be ;-)

Comment: @mgilson: man, I need some new tricks.  Everyone's caught on to my old ones..

Comment: @DSM -- They're good tricks.  It's hard to imagine that you could come up with better ones ( although, if you do come up with some better ones, please post them so I can start using them in my answers and continue raking in the upvotes without needing to actually develop any sort of personal creativity :-p )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you could combine them all into 1 super regex:

```
import re

names = ['Chris', 'Jack', 'Kim']
target = ['Chris Smith', 'I hijacked this thread', 'Kim','Christmas is here', 'CHRIS']

regex_string = '|'.join(r"(?:\b"+re.escape(x)+r"\b)" for x in names)
print regex_string
regex = re.compile(regex_string,re.I)
print [t for t in target if regex.search(t)]
```

---

A non-regex solution which will only work if the names are a single word (no whitespace):

```
new_names = set(name.lower() for name in names)
[ t for t in target if any(map(new_names.__contains__,t.lower().split())) ]
```

the `any` expression could also be written as:

```
any(x in new_names for x in t.lower().split())
```

or

```
any(x.lower() in new_names for x in t.split())
```

or, another variant which relies on `set.intersection` (suggested by @DSM below):

```
[ t for t in target if new_names.intersection(t.lower().split()) ]
```

You can profile to see which performs best if performance is really critical, otherwise **choose the one that you find to be easiest to read/understand**.

*If you're using python2.x, you'll probably want to use `itertools.imap` instead of `map` if you go that route in the above to get it to evaluate lazily -- It also makes me wonder if python provides a lazy `str.split` which would have performance on par with the non-lazy version ...

Comment: Instead of the `any` I used (changing variable names) `if new_names.intersection(t.lower().split())`.  I don't know if the gains from using the builtin `intersection` outweigh the losses from needing to keep searching after the first match is found.  I did find that the nonregex one scaled up better to a larger name set than did the regex version, but all benchmarks are lies, as they say..

Comment: Yeah, I thought about `.intersection` as well. I'm not sure which would perform better where the rubber meets the road.  `intersection` should be fast, but you can't short-circuit -- But you also don't need to create a generator which can be slow.  Definitely a job for a real-world profiler.  I've added your suggestion as another variant so OP can choose to profile it as well if desired.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 4):

this one is the simplest one i can think of:

```
[item for item in target if re.search(r'\b(%s)\b' % '|'.join(names), item)]
```

all together:

```
import re

names = ['Chris', 'Jack', 'Kim']
target = ['Chris Smith', 'I hijacked this thread', 'Kim','Christmas is here', 'CHRIS']

results = [item for item in target if re.search(r'\b(%s)\b' % '|'.join(names), item)]

print results
>>> 
['Chris Smith', 'Kim']
```

and to make it more efficient, you can compile the regex first.

```
regex = re.compile( r'\b(%s)\b' % '|'.join(names) )
[item for item in target if regex.search(item)]
```

**edit**

after considering the question and looking at some comments, i have revised the 'solution' to the following:

```
import re
names = ['Chris', 'Jack', 'Kim']
target = ['Chris Smith', 'I hijacked this thread', 'Kim','Christmas is here', 'CHRIS']
regex = re.compile( r'\b((%s))\b' % ')|('.join([re.escape(name) for name in names]), re.I )
results = [item for item in target if regex.search(item)]
```

results:

```
>>> 
['Chris Smith', 'Kim', 'CHRIS']
```

Comment: If you're going for speed, you can `re.compile` ahead of time.  Then you only build the string once

Comment: `re.compile` will have minimal benefit: the engine already caches about 30 regular expressions, however hoisting the creation of the pattern out of the loop would seem worthwhile. You probably also want to do `'|'.join(re.escape(names))` to avoid nasty side effects lest any names should happen to have special characters e.g. one of the strings might be `'Mr. Rose'` which without escaping would also match `'Mrs Rose'`.

Comment: @Duncan -- good point on escaping.  OP says that there are about 5000 names though, so you definitely need to compile as this almost certainly overflows the regex cache for any of the implementations of `re` that are in the various python distributions.

Comment: @mgilson, the solution above only generates a single (long) regular expression so it should cache just fine.

Comment: I got an 'OverFlowError: regular expression code size limit exceeded' when trying this on live data

Comment: found the reason to this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1998287/1561176 and fixed my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You're currently doing one loop inside another, iterating over two lists. That's always going to give you quadratic performance.

One local optimisation is to compile each name regex (which will make applying each regex faster). However, the big win is going to be to combine all of your regexes into one regex which you apply to each item in your input. See @mgilson's answer for how to do that. After that, your code performance should scale linearly as O(M+N), rather than O(M*N).

Comment: I didn't downvote, but compiling each regex is unlikely to be an issue unless OP has *lots* of names.  The `re` module caches the first 100 or so regexes for efficiency (stored in a dictionary, so lookup should be O(1) for the typical case).

Comment: i understand your frustration at the hit-and-run downvoting, but in this case i think i might understand why, your answer, though very informative, does not actually answer the question by giving an actual solution, some might find that unproductive, personally i think it would be great if "answers" could also be guides, and support for the actual question, though unfortunately it seems that people take "answers" to mean "pre-built solutions" these days. i wouldent take it to heart.

Comment: @mgilson (a) He has 5000 names (b) As I state explicitly, it's a local optimisation which does not take him out of M*N territory.

Comment: @InbarRose I see no point in replicating your and mgilson's code. I instead provide the reasoning why your methods are productive (which at time of writing, neither answer did).